# Algorithm for finding a plus sign in a grid

Tags: c++, algorithm, grid, breadth-first-search

I have this problem of finding the largest 'PLUS' in a given grid.
For example, If I have the following grid:

```
..#..
..#.#
#####
..#.#
..#..
```

The largest 'PLUS' in it would be of size 3 . Similarly, for

```
..#
#.#
#.#
```

The answer would be 1 as no particular 'PLUS' exists (except the origin of course).

The algorithm I have in mind goes like this:

1. Find a location with `#` and with `#` on all its 4 directions. Like `(2, 2)` in figure 1.
2. Use Breadth First Search strategy to add all its neighbors in the queue along with the direction they lie in (left, right, up, down).
3. Keep visiting and adding neighbors pertaining to that particular direction.
4. Repeat until you encounter a `.` or run out of bounds.

While doing all this, we can maintain an array which can maintain the count of `#` occurring in each direction.

Code:

```
int x[4] = {-1,0,1,0} ;
int y[4] = {0,1,0,-1} ;
int n, dir[4], result ;
char adj[2001][2001] ;

int bfs(int sx, int sy) {
    queue < pair <int, pair <int, int> > > q ;
    q.push(make_pair(0, make_pair(sx+x[0], sy+y[0]))) ;
    q.push(make_pair(1, make_pair(sx+x[1], sy+y[1]))) ;
    q.push(make_pair(2, make_pair(sx+x[2], sy+y[2]))) ;
    q.push(make_pair(3, make_pair(sx+x[3], sy+y[3]))) ;
    while (!q.empty()) {
        pair <int, pair <int, int> > curr = q.front() ;
        q.pop() ;
        int current_direction =  curr.first ;
        int current_x = curr.second.first + x[current_direction] ;
        int current_y = curr.second.second + y[current_direction] ;
        if (current_x>=0&&current_x<n&&current_y>=0&&current_y<n) {
            if (adj[current_x][current_y] == '#') {
                ++dir[current_direction] ;
                q.push(make_pair(current_direction, make_pair(current_x, current_y))) ;
            }
            else
                break ;
        }
        else
            break ;
    }
    result = *min_element(dir, dir+4) ;
    return result ;
}

int main() {
    int t ; scanf("%d", &t) ;
    while (t--) {
        scanf("%d", &n) ;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            cin >> adj[i] ;
        bool flag = true ;
        int max_plus = 0 ;
        for (int i = 1; i < n - 1; i++)
            for (int j = 1; j < n - 1; j++) {
                if (adj[i][j] == '#' && adj[i-1][j] == '#' \\
                    && adj[i][j+1] == '#' && adj[i+1][j] == '#' \\
                    && adj[i][j-1] == '#') {
                    // cout << i << " " << j << endl ;
                    flag = false ;
                    memset(dir, 2, sizeof(dir)) ;
                    max_plus = max(max_plus, bfs(i, j)) ;
                }
            }
        if(flag)
            cout << "1" << endl ;
        else
            cout << max_plus << endl ;
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```

This code seems to give a weird output (`33686019`) for figure 1. 
I can't seem to find the error I'm running into with respect to the code. Also, if there is something wrong with the algorithm I have, I'd love some advice.

Comment: \\ is added to reduce the line for SO . :p

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't exactly know what is wrong with your code and whether your algorithm is correct or not. But I don't think you need BFS to solve this problem. Create 4 matrices that keeps the number of consecutive `#`s up, down, left and right of each `#`:

```
..#..
..#.#
#####
..#.#
..#..
```

up

```
..0..
..1.0
00201
..3.2
..4..
```

down

```
..4..
..3.2
00201
..1.0
..0..
```

right

```
..0..
..0.0
43210
..0.0
..0..
```

left

```
..0..
..0.0
01234
..0.0
..0..
```

now create a matrix by keeping the minimum of 4 matrices for each element

min

```
..0..
..0.0
00200
..0.0
..0..
```

The answer is maximum of the `min` matrix.

suppose you want to count how many consecutive '#'s are behind each '#'.

```
for i from 0 to str.length
    if s[i]=='#':
        if s[i-1]=='#': // beware of i==0
            dp[i] = dp[i-1]+1
        else 
            dp[i] = 0

str ..##.###...##...
dp  ..01.012...01...
```

Comment: It will have a very high time and space complexity I suppose . Matrix can be of sizes 5000 x 5000 .

Comment: This is `O(n^2)` you can't do it better than `O(n^2)`. `O(n^2)` is acceptable for 5000.

Comment: I don't see the need for `L` factor. You just need to traverse the graph once. I think it is straightforward to calculate these matrices in one pass.

Comment: Can you give me a heads up on how would you check all `#`s in all directions for a particular `#` in one pass ? How would you go about checking till the bounds ? It'd be great if you could add it to your answer .

Comment: @saru95 it is the simplest example of dynamic programming. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Never mind, I misinterpreted your answer. But your graph for the left direction is actually the right direction again.

Comment: My god , checking a previous `#`s value . I'm sorry. I see it straight now . BTW do you see any major thing wrong with the BFS algorithm .

Comment: Well it's not a real BFS because you are not pushing all the neighbors to queue and you are not maintaining a visited list. Also you are doing that for every `#` that you see which is gonna be inefficient.